# how to force close the currently running application in android

Tags: android

i am trying to find out the list of processes which is running in the device. 
after that i want to force close all the process except my current application.
I tried using this below code . Its listing out the processed but its not killing the processes .

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

 List<RunningAppProcessInfo> process = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();  




  for (int i = 1 ;i< process.size();i++)

  {
    int pid = process.get(i).pid;            

    System.out.println("Task " + process.get(i).processName);  

    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);is 
   }
```

This above code only i tried to kill the processes. once after the killprocess called i again called the getRunningAppProcess() to check the process are killed or not. still its showing all the processes.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: this is one requirement for me... when my application runs i want to close all other applications.

Comment: But why?  I want a million pounds, but only because I want to buy nice things.  Do you understand how Android manages applications when they are not in the foreground?  It is actually pretty clever, so you don't even need task killer applications.

Answer (score 3):

> Its listing out the processed but its not killing the processes .

Of course. You do not have rights to kill other processes using `killProcess()`. I have no idea why you think you would have such a right.

> We want to kill all foreground as well as background application also.

This will crash the operating system.

If you only want your application running, build your own devices with your own firmware and your own OS and your own GUI framework, put your application on those devices, and distribute those devices.

Comment: i have created some sample applicatiions. i am trying to close my other applicaiton only.. that too not happens in killprocess()

Comment: @Ram: that is because one process does not have the right to terminate any other processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try killBackgroundProcesses() (it needs package names), you need the KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES permission for it. And you can kill your own process without a special permission (be sure to do it last).
If it still doesn't work, you need to root the phone, and do it as root.

Comment: i tried this..its working but i tried to kill the com.android.media but its not getting killed. I think there is some restriction to kill the in-built applications.Please correct me if i am wrong